# Loop on database results with several rows

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, select

I am working on a new project. It uses an access database and with help from here previously I was able to search on more than one row. The trouble is, the search only checks the last field in the database for matches. I think I need to use a for loop for each row. I have tried this below. The problem I get however is:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'returnedRows'

I do not know how to fix it or if my code is even close to achieving this.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchFor = txtSearch.Text;
    int results = 0;

    DataRow[] returnedRows;

    results = returnedRows.Length;

    if (results > 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
       {
         DataRow dr1;

         dr1 = returnedRows[i];

         for (int j = 0; j < results; j++)
         {
             DataRow dr2;
             dr2 = returnedRows[j];
             returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Select("Memory='" + searchFor + "' and HD='" + searchFor + "'");
         }

         MessageBox.Show("Maker - " + (dr1[1].ToString() + "\n" + "Model - " + (dr1[2].ToString() + "\n" + "Current Price - £" + (dr1[3].ToString()))));
       }

    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No such item");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `returnedRows` initialized? WHere is your SQL query?

Comment: You're never actually assigning anything to "returnedRows".  You have to execute some type of query against the database and place the results into this variable.  As is, the value is "null" and you can't get the length of a null value.

Comment: You aren't populating anything in your collection.  I don't see where you are getting the rows from the database?

Comment: what is assign to returnedRows? and in c# you always need to initialized.i think something missed in your posted code ,can you please post the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a reader object.  Here are some good links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UseADataReader.htm

But regardless of your initial question, you absolutely ALWAYS need to initialize any array before you use it (even to get "Length").

Comment: Sorry. I am at a complete loss. If it helps, this is what my code was built up from which may help explain some of it. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p12.html

Comment: SUGGESTION: cut/paste one of the examples I gave you and try it out.